# Simple Instrumentation Test Fails in Android (Dagger Injection Issue)

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, instrumentation

I am trying to run a simple instrumentation test on an Android emulator:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MainActivityTest{
    @Test
    fun test_openPage() {
        val activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
    }
}
```

It throws `RunTimeException` with a message:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: android.app.Application does not implement dagger.android.HasAndroidInjector`

However my application class `MyApplication` actually implements `HasAndroidInjector`, it seems instrumentation test mocks an application class which does not implement it.

How can I make the test to use `MyApplication`?